# RIA share.cs class is generated for client but there are ambiguity problems

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

I have this class in RIA service ArtifactToExport.  It gets generated on the client but I get the following errors.

Error   2   Missing partial modifier on declaration of type ArifactToExport'; another partial declaration of this type exists   C:\Source\AlmExportInfo.shared.cs   142 18  RIA.Models

NullableEndpoint is an Enum

```
public class ArifactToExport
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int RaptorItemId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public NullableEndpoint ConflictWinner { get; set; }
}
```

I also am unable to use these in the client as I get errors relating to the properties being ambigous (aka, they exist twice).  Any recommendations on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states: You forgot to place the partial modifier to the class. Use:

```
public partial class ArifactToExport 
{ 
    [XmlAttribute] 
    public int RaptorItemId { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute] 
    public NullableEndpoint ConflictWinner { get; set; } 
}
```

and read this: [MSDN: Partial Class Definitions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That's not really the point unless I am missing something which is entirely possible as I am new to RIA Services.  If the class is marked as shared it generates the class on the client and now you will get errors relating to the class already contains a definition for each of the properties.

The type '' already contains a definition for 'AlmItemDestinationId'

I don't know why..

Comment: Partial is a symptom of the problem, but the root cause lies elsewhere

Comment: Well.. if you publish ArtifactToExport in your RIA Service, there is no point in sharing it, since RIA tools will generate the class on the client anyway. If you want a class to be useable on the server and the client but not in the service, share it.